# Can prolog be used to determine invalid inference?

Tags: prolog, logic, boolean-logic, clpb

If I have two premises as follows:

1. a -> c (a implies c)
2. b -> c (b implies c)

and a derived conclusion:

3. a -> b (a therefore implies b),

then the conclusion can be shown to be invalid because:

a -> c is valid for statement #1 when a is true and c is true, and
b -> c is valid for statement #2 when b is false and c is true. This leads to a -> b when a is true and b is false, a direct contradiction of statement #3.

Or, per proof with a truth table that contains a line for where the premises are true but the conclusion is false:

[Truth Table with true premises and false conclusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WemIU.gif)

My question is: "Is there a way to use prolog to show that the assertions of statements #1 and #2 contradict the conclusion of statement #3? If so, what is a clear and concise way to do so?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  **library(clpb)**:

Firstly assign to a variable Expr your expression:

`Expr = ((A + ~C)*(B + ~C)+(~(A + ~B))`.

Note that:

- '+' stands for logical OR
- '*' for logical AND
- '~' for logical NOT
  Also `A->B` is equivalent with `A+(~B)`. So the above expression is equivalent with `((A->C),(B->C))-> (A->C)` where we wrote `'->'` using `+,~` and `','` with `*`.

Now if we query:

```
?-  use_module(library(clpb)).
true.
?- Expr=((A + ~C)*(B + ~C))+(~(A + ~B)),taut(Expr,T).
false.
```

Predicate **taut/2** takes as input an clpb Expression and returns T=1 if it tautology, T=0 if expression cannot be satisfied and fails in any other case. So the fact that the above query failed means that Expr was nor a tautology neither could not be satisfied, it meant that it could be satisfied.

Also by querying:

```
?- Expr=((A + ~C)*(B + ~C))+(~(A + ~B)),sat(Expr).
Expr = (A+ ~C)* (B+ ~C)+ ~ (A+ ~B),
sat(1#C#C*B),
sat(A=:=A).
```

Predicate `sat/1` returns True iff the Boolean expression is satisfiable and gives the answer that the above Expression is satisfiable when:

```
sat(1#C#C*B),
sat(A=:=A).
```

where `'#'` is the `exclusive OR` which means that your expression (we know from taut/2 that is satisfiable) is satisfied when `1#C#C*B` is satisfied.

Another solution without using libraries could be:

```
truth(X):-member(X,[true,false]).

test_truth(A,B,C):-
  truth(A),
  truth(B),
  truth(C),
  ((A->C),(B->C)->(A->C)).
```

Example:

```
?- test_truth(A,B,C).
A = B, B = C, C = true ;
false.
```

Also if I understood correctly from your comment, to collect all possible solutions you could write:

```
?- findall([A,B,C],test_truth(A,B,C),L).
L = [[true, true, true]].
```

Which gives a list of lists, where the inner lists have the form `[true,true,true]` in the above example which means a solution is `A=true,B=true,C=true` and in the above case it has only one solution.

To find all contradictions you could write:

```
 truth(X):-member(X,[true,false]).

    test_truth(A,B,C):-
      truth(A),
      truth(B),
      truth(C),
    not( (\+ ((\+A; C),(\+B ; C)) ; (\+A ; B)) ).
```

last line could also been written as:

```
not( ( (A->C;true),(B->C;true) ) -> (A->B;true) ;true ).
```

Example:

```
  ?- findall([A,B,C],test_truth(A,B,C),L).
L = [[true, false, true]].
```

Comment: Very nice answer! In fact, as you correctly say, `sat/1` succeeds *iff* the expression is satisfiable, so we know from the fact that it succeeds in this case already that the whole expression is satisfiable! Thus, there is actually no reason to use `taut/2` to find this out. I only mention this for completeness and simplicity.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just mentioned taut/2 because it is useful and it exactly answer the question because it gives straight the answer whether expr is tautology,satisfiable or not satisfiable. The same and more info we can find from sat/1 ,I mentioned both because both are useful and solve the problem, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Great! I only mentioned this for completeness.

Comment: Many thanks! However, the piece that it seems I omitted from my question is whether a solution set can be produced. That is, show that the answer is invalid specifically for a:true, b:false, c:true. The ultimate objective is to collect a large chain of premises/conclusions and then display contradictions. Think of, say, a permissions model for users where a contradiction is buried in the model that allows a user access to content, but only if they authenticated in a certain way, had access to 2  tiers of data, but not all, etc. I had imagined "bagof" was going to be in the mix...

Comment: The solution is described by sat(1#C#C*B) but yes this is not straight, I edited my answer adding a second solution that gives A,B,C where the expression is true else it fails and does not use libraries. Though I am not sure that it is as strong-efficient solution as using library.

Comment: Very nice! I think it would be great to also include how `labeling/1` can be used to obtain a concrete counterexample with CLP(B).

Comment: The problem I think with labeling/1 is that it gives a variable 1 or 0 and not true or false so I don't know how it could be used....It would be very easy to produce a counterexample in the second solution by adding not(expession) instead of expression...

Comment: I admit I'm struggling to understand the answer, but this is in part because I'm new to Prolog. It seems likely the answer has already been supplied, but what I was perhaps hoping to see was something like:

Comment: ? - findall([A,B,C],discover_contradictions(A,B,C),L).

Comment: discover_contradictions found contradiction in (A=true, B=false, C=true). Again, the ultimate aim here is to find contradictions among software requirements that have truth values that should ultimately never conflict with one another (i.e.,be tautological) but may, as in:If administrator, user is taken to the landing page.
If privileged, user is taken to the landing page.
Expected: If administrator, then privileged.

Comment: To find ALL the contradictions is easy (using findall) ,In my second answer I find all the (A,B,C) that evaluate the expression to true but I could change it a little bit to find all contradictions, Is that what you're asking??

Comment: Yes I think finding all contradictions is the right place to start. The example I provided only has one that I am aware of, but ideally I'd like to have a chain of premises and conclusions (sometimes the conclusion becoming a premise elsewhere in the collection), perhaps hundreds of them, that should, taken together, be a tautology. But collecting these contradictions would help reveal where the ideas break down.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not seeing what I expect. If you follow the link above to the truth table generated at Wolfram Alpha, it only shows one set of values that is false for the asserted premise and conclusion. Perhaps I'm not explaining myself well, or I have a core mistake in my notion about what the truth table is showing me? That line in the truth table, as I have it, demonstrates that the premises and conclusion are not tautological.

Comment: Yes that's because I have  (A->C) and not (A->B) that's a typo, thanks for pointing out...

Comment: Yes, I think this works for me. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: glad that helped!!

Answer (score 2):

@coder has already given a very good answer, using [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb) constraints.

I would like to show a slightly different way to show that the conclusion does *not* follow from the premises, also using CLP(B).

The main difference is that I post *individual* `sat/1` constraints for each of the premises, and then use `taut/2` to see whether the conclusion follows from the premises.

The first premise is:

> a → c

In CLP(B), you can express this as:

```
sat(A =< C)
```

The second premise, i.e., b → c, becomes:

```
sat(B =< C)
```

If the a → b followed from these premises, then `taut/2` would **succeed** with `T = 1` in:

```
?- sat(A =< C), sat(B =< C), taut(A =< B, T).
false.
```

Since it doesn't, we know that the conclusion does not follow from the premises.

We can ask CLP(B) to show a **counterexample**, i.e., an assignment of truth values to variables where a → c and b → c both hold, and a → b does not hold:

```
?- sat(A =< C), sat(B =< C), sat(~(A =< B)).
A = C, C = 1,
B = 0.
```

Simply posting the constraints *suffices* to show the unique counterexample that exists in this case. If the counterexample were not unique, we could use `labeling/1` to produce ground instances, for example: `labeling([A,B,C])`.

For comparison, consider for example:

```
?- sat(A =< B), sat(B =< C), taut(A =< C, T).
T = 1,
sat(A=:=A*B),
sat(B=:=B*C).
```

This shows that a → c follows from a → b ∧ b → c.